# How to Move File with the folder in a ftp file path to local directory using C#

Tags: c#, ftp

How to Move File with the folder in a ftp file path to local directory using C#

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient()) {
        ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("RAYSOFT", "raysoft");
        ftpClient.DownloadFile("ftp://RAYSOFT@192.168.8.101/10001/ajax.txt", @"C:\\SmartProject\ajax.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: here, only copying the file.I need to copy the file with "10001" directory.

Comment: How to Download Folders, SubFolders and Files from FTP Server to Local Machine